# Attach receptacle box to baseboard via screws through plaster ears?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, baseboard, old-work

The plaster ears on old work metal receptacle boxes (see [example](http://www.homedepot.com/p/3-1-2-in-Deep-Gangable-Switch-Box-with-1-2-in-KO-s-and-Plaster-Ears-8590/202056179)) each have two holes on the face of them. Is it ok to put screws through these holes to secure the box to baseboard?

In this particular case, I'm replacing an old receptacle and box that's located on the baseboard. The hole for the receptacle box is sized such that the box itself fits through cleanly, but not the plaster ears, which lie flat against the baseboard. I can use a set of those thin metal switch box supports (see [example](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Old-Work-Switch-Box-Supports-8977/100547662?keyword=100547662)), but it seems the easiest and most secure thing to do would be just to drive 4 screws through the holes in the plaster ears into the baseboard. Is that allowed?

Thanks for your help!

*** Image added***
(note that I would snap the removable ears off the receptacle so that they don't block the holes on the receptacle box's plaster ears)

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of your situation?

Comment: Image added to original post.

Comment: What model box are you putting here?

Comment: "2-1/2 in. Deep Gangable Switch Box with 1/2 in. KO's and Plaster Ears"

Comment: Also known as a Raco 8500 (probably better to post a make/model instead of a description next time)

Comment: Ok. In any case, every steel old work box with plaster ears that I can find has the same two holes in each plaster ear. I guess another way of asking the question would be, do those two holes have any purpose? Are they intended as screw-holes, or do they have some other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The holes in the plaster ears of the box will take screws very well. That is what usually holds the box in place when it is mounted in a cabinet.

To allow the cover plate to set well, you could use 4 gauge screws or a larger diameter and countersink the holes in the mounting ears a bit to help let the receptacle set tight to the face of the box. You would do well to break off the ears on the receptacle at the score lines to help clear the screw heads too.

Comment: Great, thank you! After reading your reply, I did a quick image search for "cabinet electrical box" and was able to find this image, which shows what I was asking about: http://images.meredith.com/diy/images/2009/03/p_SCW_218_03.jpg. And yes, I'll snap the ears off the receptacle itself (along the score lines). Thanks again!

Comment: (And P.S. - thank you for taking the time to answer what was probably a very, very basic question!)